# Проблема с ошибкой IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, циклы, list

Дан набор из N целых положительных чисел. Необходимо выбрать из набора произвольное количество чисел так, чтобы их сумма была как можно больше и при этом не делилась на 6. В ответе нужно указать количество выбранных чисел и их сумму.
Если получить нужную сумму невозможно, считается, что выбрано 0 чисел и их сумма равна 0.

```
a = []
N = int(input())
maxsum=0
for i in range(N):
    a.append(int(input()))
a.sort(reverse=True)
for j in range(N):
    sum = a[j] #строка 8
    maxsum += sum
    if maxsum%6==0 and a!=[]:
        a.sort()
        a.pop(0)
        sum=maxsum=0
        for o in range(len(a)):
            sum = a[o]
            maxsum += sum
if maxsum%6!=0: 
    print(len(a),maxsum)
```

Почему ошибка *IndexError: list index out of range* в строке 8 выдается каждый раз, когда в массив ***а*** вводится число ***6***? Объясните, пожалуйста, несложным языком новичку. Также можно исправить некоторые корявости кода. В целом программа работает за исключением этого случая с шестеркой.

Comment: Пометьте в коде где находится строка 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[itertools.combinations](http://www.ilnurgi1.ru/docs/python/modules/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)
итератор, который возвращает все возможные последовательности из r элементов, взятых из итерируемого объекта n_. Последовательности выдаются в лексикографическом порядке сортировки. Если входной итератор отсортированный, последовательности будут создаваться в отсортированном порядке.
Элементы считаются уникальными в зависимости от их положения.

```
import itertools, random

def combinator(n_: list):
    n_.sort(reverse=True)
    for r in reversed(range(len(n_)+1)):
        for n in itertools.combinations(n_, r):
            sn = sum(n)
            if sn % 6:
                return len(n), sn

N = [random.randrange(9) for _ in range(10)]
print(combinator(N))
```

Comment: В общем ничего не понял, надеюсь это должно было мне помочь.

Comment: это вариант решения вашей задачи

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка происходит из-за того что вы внутри цикла, проходящего по списку, уменьшаете сам список. В результате, в какой-то момент окажется, что индекс `j` выходит за реальные границы списка. В общем случае не рекомендуется в цикле изменять список, по которому цикл проходит (по крайней мере, не изменять его размеры), иначе будете долго пытаться отловить многочисленные непонятные ошибки.

Если в условии задачи изменить "произвольное количество чисел" на "максимальное количество чисел", то алгоритм будет таким:

1. Есть исходный список, сортируем его
2. Считаем сумму всех элементов - если она не кратна 6, то возвращаем весь список
3. Если сумма кратна 6 - удаляем из списка минимальный элемент, не кратный 6, в итоге сумма списка становится не кратной 6. Сразу возвращаем оставшиеся элементы.
4. Если все элементы списка кратны 6, то возвращаем пустой список.

Реализация:

```
import random

def sum_not_mul_6(s):
    s = sorted(s)  # п. 1

    if sum(s) % 6 != 0:  # п. 2
        return s

    for i, item in enumerate(s):  # п. 3
        if item % 6 != 0:
            del s[i]
            return s

    return []  # п. 4

s = [random.randrange(9) for _ in range(10)]

print(s, sum(s))  # Пример вывода: [7, 8, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 7, 6, 1] 48

x = sum_not_mul_6(s)

print(x, sum(x))  # Пример вывода: [1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8] 47
```

Для вывода *всех* вариантов сочетаний элементов списка, сумма которых не кратна 6 можно использовать `itertools.combinations`, как в ответе **vadim vaduxa**.

Answer (score -1):

У кого возникает такая проблема, в цикле `for` нужно использовать не `sum = a[j]`, а просто `sum = j`.